Scroll eventListener with throttle or passive: true
I'm trying to create the best scroll experience for my users.
I'm creating sticky element when the user scrolls down the page - among other things. I'm using the IntersectionObserver API to detect when the element is in the viewport.
But one thing I'm unsure of.
How should I handle scroll events in the most optimal way?
Should I use a debounce function like this:
const debounce = (func, wait, immediate) => {
    let timeout;
    return function () {
        let context = this,
            args = arguments;
        let later = () => {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate)
                func.apply(context, args);
        };
        let callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow)
            func.apply(context, args);
    };
}
  
window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(() => {
   // Run function
}, 150));

Or should I use passive: true like this:
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
   // Run function
}, {
    passive: true
});

Or a combination?

Completely depends on what you want to do on a scroll event. If you want to prevent default scroll behavior and instead update a scroll position manually based on some table row height or something, you can't use a passive event listener anyway

I'm creating a sticky element when the user scrolls down the page - among other things. I'm using the IntersectionObserver API to detect when the element is in the viewport.

1- passive option can be set to true when you are pretty sure that preventDefault will never be needed in your handler.
2- the use of debounce (which typically means 'consider the emitted value only after a time span has passed') totally depends on the use case, for example, debounce can be a good fit for the need to pause emissions before executing some logic.
